# Whats the best way to map users to connection ids

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I want to map user's to connection id's when they connect to my hub class, what is a good strategy for doing this efficiently?  I want to associate a user's profile with his connection id so when I check what users are in a particular signalr group I can each user's profile info easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically if you're not worried about maintaining state you could solve this with a poor man's in memory `ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentBag<string>>`, but I would assume you are trying to be a little more scalable/fault tolerant than that.

[JabbR](https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR), which is the flagship testbed chat application for the SignalR framework, stores the connected client details in a table in its DB (which happens to be SQL). It has a mapping of the single ChatUser -> to many ChatClient instances (one-to-many). This way, when a logical user is logged in, it knows who that user is logically and can also make sure it can direct the proper messages to all the connected client instances that user might currently have open. [You can find that specific implementation here](https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR/blob/master/JabbR/Services/ChatService.cs#L588) if you're interested in learning more about it.

Comment: Do you have to consider concurrency for the db solution?  Also, how do you handle when the server goes down?  All the mappings are still saved in the database, so would you have to  truncate the table everytime you start up the ap?

Comment: Sure, you have to handle all the usual concurrency/scalability problems that you'd have to handle in any app. As for connected users, yes, you would have to figure out what's going on when you startup again. JabbR does this by clearing the entire table out during app start, though this is simplistic, brute force and probably not the most elegant solution you could have... especially for a farm hosted application:  https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR/blob/master/JabbR/App_Start/Bootstrapper.cs#L146

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what would be your suggestion in that case then.  How would i be able to manage it in a farm hosted application.  One server shuts off, how will it know from there on which users to remove out of the table?

Comment: Off top of my head? Write the server identifier that the user was connected to to the table as well and clear only those out when that server starts up? If that server never comes back up, the "sweep" algorithm to detect disconnected clients and clear them would eventually clear them anyway.